# Fix LCD Display Issue

Tags: lcd

Just since yesterday, I notice there is a "white spray" at the top right corner of my LCD screen. The "white spray" is more obvious when the screen is in dark color. At first, I thought it is dirt or scratches on my monitor, but when I turn off monitor, the "white spray" is gone.

I did some Google search and find some articles on fixing stuck pixel. But I guess my case here is not stuck pixel. What do you think causes the problem? Is it back light? Is there any chances I can fix the problem myself?

Thank you.

[image: Red circle shows problem area]

Comment: May be monitoring is getting damaged. LCD screens have a chance to get damaged more.

Comment: Have you recently changed your set-up? Say, for instance, changing the cable you connect to your tower with, or installing a new GPU?

Comment: @DevonParsons Nope, I didn't do anything or change anything to my system recently.

Answer (score 0):

This is called flashlighting or clouding. It is caused by the blacklight bleeding though. You can try the following techniques, at your own risk:

1. Slightly twist the display frame in different directions to see if there's an effect.
2. Loosen the panel's screws, shake the panel slightly, then tighten them again.
3. Tap or massage the area of the screen that shows the problem.